# Structural boards in attic?

Tags: structural

I want remove the header to install floor to ceiling closet doors for our master bedroom. In the attic above the header three boards sit and run to the roof (see picture). Are these boards structural?

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. They look important to me, but it's hard to tell from here. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they appear to be. The two on the right looks like they are holding a 2X to the underside of the roof rafters. I was brought up in the trade calling this a "strongback". The closest one has a notch around the strongback which strongly suggests a structural connection. The picture does not show clearly the far side to tell if it is notched as well.